# Optimize bulk operation MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, bulkinsert

To bulkWrite() I pass array of following documents where field `a` is the same across every document.

```
updateMany: {
    filter: {
        a: "x"
        b: x
    },
    update: {
        $set: {...obj}
    },
    upsert: true
}
```

Does mongodb `bulkWrite` filter collection at first stage to save all documents with field `a` and then perform search on field b on that collection?

Comment: you mean like one update to use the search results of another update? i dont think its happening, also each update can change the document and make their search results wrong. i am not sure what you mean

Comment: The filter is for searching the document(s) with the specified field(s) - this is true even within a bulk write operation.